# Printed colored text is brighter than usual

Tags: printer

I have the following printer: `HP Officejet 4500 G510n-z`.
Normally I print a colored text (mostly black, but some is colored in green, blue, orange, purple).
The last time I printed - the blue text became much brighter than usual.  Also the orange and purple text is missing ink in tiny areas of the letters.
The `Estimated Ink Levels` seen via the firmware website show that the black cartridge is *nearly empty*, though the Tri-color cartridge is (3/4) full.
Also I printed a "Self -Test Report" and it seems valid.

I don't understand, what could be the problem?
Already looked in [the manual for Print Diagnostic](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01968417#Print_Diagnostic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the heads? The blue is probably looking brighter because it isn't being mixed with the other inks properly to make the normal colour.

Sometimes the microscopic holes that the printer squirts ink through can get clogged with dust or dried ink. Cleaning the heads will force ink through all the holes at extreme pressure in an attempt to clear them. The process will use a lot of ink so you might want to have some spare cartridges available if they are low.

Step 8 of your [link](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01968417#Print_Diagnostic) explains how to clean the heads.

> 1. Load plain, white paper into the input tray.
> 2. Press Setup.
> 3. Select Tools, and then select Clean Cartridge.
>
> The printer prints one page.

Answer (score 1):

Your description (bright blue, missing parts in orange and purple letters) indicates that one or more of the magenta jets are blocked. Print a Diagnostic Report (step 7 in your link) to check. If that is indeed the problem, clean the heads as explained by Burgi.